# Rewriting the limit $e^{f(x)}$

Tags: limits

I've seen in multiple places that a limit

$\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{f(x)}$

can be rewritten as

$e^{\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)}$.

However, I searched Google (and this Stack Exchange) for limit properties, but none of them seem to state this as a rule or imply it, either. Is there a way to prove this, and is there a rule which states this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\lim_{x\to \infty }f(x)$ exists, the continuity of $x\longmapsto e^x$ gives you the result directly. If $\lim_{x\to \infty }f(x)=+\infty $, it's a fact that $x\longmapsto e^x$ is strictly increasing and that $\lim_{x\to \infty }e^{x}=+\infty $ will give you the result. And if $\lim_{x\to \infty }f(x)$ doesn't exist, then it makes no sense to write $\lim_{x\to\infty }f(x)$.

Comment: Thanks! What about for any number, not just for infinity?

Comment: what do you mean ? @SkeletonBow

Comment: I really don't know

Comment: ????? @SkeletonBow

Comment: @SkeletonBow Nothing strange will happen then. If $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)=A$, then we get that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} e^{f(x)}=e^{\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)}=e^A$. It's a direct consequence of the continuity of the exponential function.

Comment: @Scounged superb. Thank you very much!